# how can i select all name into one group at the same class?

Tags: sql, linq, sqlcommand

If I have a data table like this

```
 Class |  Name  
   1   |   a 
   1   |   b 
   1   |   c 
   2   |   d 
   2   |   e
```

and I want my result from the group by class = 1
and the result is  **1 , a/b/c**  how can i get it by SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var grouped = from l in list
               group l by l.class into names
               select new { class=l.class, names = names }
```